# Trigger an event continuously in KinectExplorer-WPF solution

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect-sdk

I'm new in programming C# and xaml. I started to modify the KinectExplorer-WPF solution for Microsoft Kinect, in order to make it useful for my purposes. I modify the Kinect Window to add a new panel in which I show a sequence of images that represent some positions that could be reached by a person standing in front of the Kinect. 
This is the code that I've added to KinectWindow.xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="400" >
        <Grid Name="ExerciseViewerHost" Width="398" Height="645" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Grid Name="ExerciseVis" Background="{StaticResource DarkNeutralBrush}">
                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Name="Exerc" CommandManager.Executed="Change_Position" Margin="5 5 5 5" />
                </Viewbox>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" FontWeight="DemiBold"  Text="{Binding TextBox1Text, ElementName=root}" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="36,105,36,0" Height="45"  Width="328" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

"Change_Position" is the event that change image when a parameter is reached (in particular a max counter value) and it is defined in KinectWindow.xaml.cs as

`private void Change_Position(object sender, EventArgs e)`

and it is triggered by a `DispatcherTimer` every 0 seconds in

`DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
 dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Change_Position);
 dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
 dispatcherTimer.Start();`

The code that I've described works properly, but my question is very simple... there's a more "elegant" way to trigger this event continuously (not with a Timer)?
Has anyone some parts of code that could share with me to solve my problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`CompositionTarget.Rendering`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, which fires every time WPF renders a scene. Don't forget to unhook the event handler when you don't need it as it can be rather expensive.